# Not Getting text()[1] element in VBA/Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, webdriver

> FindElementsByXPath, VBA, Selenium

I am using vba/selenium webdriver. I couldn't pull the data.
can anyone solve this problem?

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[47]/div/div[4]/div/span[2]/text()[1]
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[47]/div/div[4]/div/span[2]/text()[2]   
/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[47]/div/div[4]/div/span[2]/text()[3]
```

All 3 texts are in the same class in the span tag.

```
<span class="_9s321"> "Stock List" "Price" "Change" </span>


webdriver.FindElementsByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[47]/div/div[4]/div/span[2]/text()[1]") - Invalid Selector 
webdriver.Text.ToExcel ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA1").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Please update your post to include your code.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while copy paste. Thanks for reminding. I have now updated the message.

Comment: Can you share the HTML snippet ?

Comment: tehere is https://ibb.co/9WxZmm5